# Looking for examples of iOS's keyboard interactions with a web form dropdowns

Tags: web-app, mobile-web, drop-down-list, webforms

Looking for resources or examples for the behavior of a dropdown and how the iOS keyboard interacts with a web form version of a dropdown. How close does the keyboard slide near the input, and how many dropdown options are available? (I know this can be set so only a certain amount displays. But what is the default behavior when iOS Safari interacts with a dropdown in a form? )

Screenshots or links to resources would be great. If this is not the correct type of question, please add a good resource or site in the comments where something like this is discussed.

Thanks